# Generating secure random numbers in Rust

Tags: random, rust, rust-obsolete

I can see I have to import like this:

```
use std::io::IoResult;
use std::num::{Int, ToPrimitive};
use std::rand::{OsRng, Rng};
```

Then make a new instance of OsRng, and try to generate a new u32 int from it

```
fn main() {

  let mut rng = OsRng::new();

  let num:u32 = rng.next_u32();
  println!("{}",num);
}
```

However I get the error type `core::result::Result<std::rand::os::imp::OsRng, std::io::IoError>` does not implement any method in scope named `next_u32`

But the rust documentation clearly says there is a function `next_u32`? http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rand/struct.OsRng.html

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem here is that `OsRng::new()` does not return an `OsRng` instance, but an `IoResult<OsRng>`. Because the program can fail to fetch the OS random number generator.

A sample use would be:

```
use std::rand::{OsRng, Rng};

fn main() {

    let mut rng = match OsRng::new() {
        Ok(g) => g,
        Err(e) => panic!("Failed to obtain OS RNG: {}", e)
    };

    let num:u32 = rng.next_u32();
    println!("{}",num);
}
```

Comment: is try!(OsRng::new()) similar to that match statement?


**perhaps not I just tried it. and got an error.

Is there a reason you can't just import use std::rand:OsRng instead of {OsRng, Rng} ?

Comment: @leshow To use `try!()` you need the function calling `OsRng::new()` to return a `IoResult<_>` (it'll to an early return on error). It's in fact a quite simple macro: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html

Comment: @leshow You need to import the trait `Rng` to use it's implementation on `OsRng`. In your case, the method `next_u32()`.

Comment: but OsRng::new() DOES return an IoResult, so can't I use

let mut rng = try!(OsRng::new());

Comment: The problem is not whether `OsRng::new()` returns an `IoResult`, but the function *calling it*. Because as `try!` expands to `return Err(..)`, your function must be compatible with it.

Comment: how might I make my function compatible so that I can use try!()? just for curiousity sake

Comment: For modern Rust use `use rand::{OsRng, Rng}` with the `rand` crate.

Answer (score 3):

FYI: The API has changed in the latest version, see https://rust-random.github.io/book/update-0.7.html

TL;DR version, use https://github.com/rust-random/getrandom

```
fn get_random_buf() -> Result<[u8; 32], getrandom::Error> {
    let mut buf = [0u8; 32];
    getrandom::getrandom(&mut buf)?;
    Ok(buf)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A search for generating secure random numbers on Rust returned this SO question, but as a comment on the current answer states, Rust no longer includes random number generation in the standard library.  Here's an updated example (as of Jan. 2017):

#### Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.3.0"
```

#### main.rs

```
extern crate rand;
use rand::{OsRng, Rng};

fn main() {
    let mut rng = OsRng::new().expect("Error opening random number generator");
    println!("Random: {}", rng.next_u32());
}
```

Useful reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/index.html#cryptographic-security

---

Otherwise, using the code from the original answer gives this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::rand::Rng`
 --> src/main.rs:5:24
  |
5 | use std::rand::{OsRng, Rng};
  |                        ^^^ no `Rng` in `std::rand`

error: module `rand` is private
 --> src/main.rs:5:17
  |
5 | use std::rand::{OsRng, Rng};
  |                 ^^^^^

error: module `rand` is private
 --> src/main.rs:5:24
  |
5 | use std::rand::{OsRng, Rng};
  |                        ^^^

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```